# SQL Query's not working and PHP questions

Tags: php, sql, backend

I'm kinda new to PHP and only using it for the backend of my Android App.

I've got three strings that I'm sending to the PHP from my Android App. I want to query a table called 'users' and find the userid of the username that was sent from my Android App and then inset the data into a seperate table called 'msg'.

I've tried for my life and I cannot get it to work, plus I haven't even finished.

thanks and helping me would be pretty amazing, as I'm new to PHP and can't finish off the rest of the code.

PHP:

```
    <?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$frienduser = $_POST ['frienduser'];

/*mysql data below */ 
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'removemypasswords', 'again');
if(!dbc) {
die("Something went wrong! Try again...");
}
/* select database */ 
$db_select = mysql_select_db("andagain, $dbc");
if (!db_select){
die("Can't connect :" .mysql_error);
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users WHERE usernames ='$usernames'");
$query1 = mysql_query(INSERT INTO  `gtanews1_zips54`.`msg` (
`id` ,
`friendid` ,
`msg`
)
VALUES (
'$query',  '$frienduser',  'msg'
);
echo ($msg);


?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about the error ?

Comment: the first query should be `SELECT *` (select all) or the field name you are trying to get

Comment: There is no question in here.

Comment: also you cant pass `$query` as a value to `$query1`

Comment: I suggest you first start with learning what you are doing before handling user data. And expose it in public because of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Nope, all the passwords are encrypted.

Comment: @TheBlueCat yet I could easily download the entire database with all info in it. encrypted passwords or not. I also wonder how you encrypted the passwords.

Comment: Ok, go on. I changed all the usernames when I uploaded this. If you think you can download it, do it.

Comment: haha, you have so many problems in this code. Not just your query

Comment: @TheBlueCat just give me the link and I might just do that

Comment: gta5news.com   now, go and crack it.

Comment: @Ronnie I've spent about ten minutes with PHP I don't understand why that's funny.

Comment: google some php/mysql tutorials and you wont have questions like these

Answer (score 0):

how about putting quotes around $query1 like

```
$query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gtanews1_zips54.msg (`id` ,`friendid` ,`msg`)
VALUES ('$query',  '$frienduser',  'msg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usernames ='$username'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gtanews1_zips54.msg (id,friendid,msg) VALUES ('" . $result['yourField'] . "', '$frienduser','$msg')");
```

Answer (score 0):

your mysql select db code is wrong. you need to have the quotes before the comma

mysql_select_db("andagain", $dbc);

also place quotes at the end of your query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users  WHERE usernames ='$usernames'"); $query1 = mysql_query(INSERT INTO `gtanews1_zips54`.`msg` ( `id` , `friendid` , `msg` ) VALUES ( '$query', '$frienduser', 'msg' )");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going wrong here:

```
   <?php

$username = $_POST['username'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
$frienduser = $_POST ['frienduser'];

/*mysql data below */ 
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'removemypasswords', 'again');
if(!$dbc) {  //- You forgot the dollar $ sign on $dbc
die("Something went wrong! Try again...");
}
/* select database */ 
$db_select = mysql_select_db("andagain", $dbc);  //- You had the entire thing quoted, quotes are just around "andagain"
if (!db_select){
die("Can't connect :" .mysql_error());  //- You forgot the parentheses after mysql_error  
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM users WHERE usernames ='$usernames'");
//- You need to actually get the results out of the query object
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
if (!$row) {
    die('User not found');
}
$user_id = $row['id']; //- Or whatever the column is called
$query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `gtanews1_zips54`.`msg` (
`id` ,
`friendid` ,
`msg`
)
VALUES (
'$user_id',  '$frienduser',  'msg'
");   //- You forgot to put quotes around this query
echo ($msg);


?>
```

And that's just to start, there may be other problems depending on your database schema / data transfer format.

Also, you're wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: How can I advoid SQL injection? I'm not to sure if matters, I'm getting the data from an Android app.

Comment: Anyone can send an http request to this script and do whatever they so desire with your database.  The basic method is to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on any string you're going to put in a query (`intval()` for ints); the better method is to use the mysqli library and create prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

your code have many errors .

> 1. $db_select = mysql_select_db (andagain, $dbc);
> 2. $query = mysql_query('SELECT FROM users WHERE usernames ="$usernames"');

since Stackoverflow is not a community for fixing codes bugs ..so i am leaving this job for you .

below are some points which can help you to fix all errors ?

1. Variable-substitution cann't be dont  with single quotes (') . double quotes allow variable substitution .
2. to escape quotes inside quotes , we use \
3. parameter cannot be encapsulated with double quotes .

Comment: Thanks, I am new to PHP and as of yet still struggling with the code compared to C & Java.